# What is missing to get correct output. I am trying to print Maximum and minimum in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I run this code in browser console or any JavaScript environment, I get max and min as 1,1. Could someone help me to find the error.

```
var arr = [1,4,6,3];
function maxAndMin(arr) {
var max = arr[0];
var min = arr[0];
for(var i=0; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
  if(arr[i] > max) {
  max = arr[i];
}
  if(arr[i] < min) {
  min = arr[i];
}}
console.log("Max:",max,"Min:",min);
}  

 maxAndMin(arr);
```

Comment: Please [edit] and tag a language. [tag:javascript]?

Answer (score 2):

`arr.lenght` has a typo, and is returning an undefined back.  So you never iterate the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo with `lenhgt`. Also, I recommend starting your loop from 1, since the 0'th element is already processed at initialization time.

```js
    var arr = [1,4,6,3];
    function maxAndMin(arr) {
    var max = arr[0];
    var min = arr[0];
    for(var i=1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
      if(arr[i] < min) {
      min = arr[i];
    }}
    console.log("Max:",max,"Min:",min);
    }  

     maxAndMin(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Javascript, then there is an alternate / easy way to find min and max of an array. Its just a one-liner

```js
var arr = [1,4,6,3];

const min = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)[0];
const max = arr.sort((a,b) => b-a)[0];

console.log('Original Array ==>', arr);
console.log('Min ==>', min);
console.log('Max ==>', max);
```

this way, you can reduce run time of your function without any for-loops and if-else loops.